# Jquery filter on href value

Tags: jquery, dom

if I have a table setup as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td onclick="res(1800, this, 10393718);"><a class="bgred" href="http://thewebsite.com/int/index.php?action=getrec&amp;vtick=XXXXXX">X</a></td>
<td onclick="res(1815, this, 10393718);"><a class="bgred" href="http://thewebsite.com/int/index.php?action=getrec&amp;vtick=XXXXXX">X</a></td>
<td onclick="res(1830, this, 10393718);"><a class="bgred" href="http://thewebsite.com/int/index.php?action=getrec&amp;vtick=10393718">X</a></td>
<td onclick="res(1900, this, 10394225);"><a class="bgred" href="http://thewebsite.com/int/index.php?action=getrec&amp;vtick=10394225">X</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Using Jquery:
How can I iterate over the DOM and set the href values to # and remove the the onclick attributes from all TD's where the href value contains 'vtick=XXXXXX' so that this example would endup looking like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a class="bgred" href="#">X</a></td>
<td><a class="bgred" href="#">X</a></td>
<td onclick="res(1830, this, 10393718);"><a class="bgred" href="http://thewebsite.com/int/index.php?action=getrec&amp;vtick=10393718">X</a></td>
<td onclick="res(1900, this, 10394225);"><a class="bgred" href="http://thewebsite.com/int/index.php?action=getrec&amp;vtick=10394225">X</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

I was trying to build off of this `$( "td:contains('XXXXXX')" ).removeAttr( "onclick" );` but this just doesn't work in the way i need it to so i need help.

Comment: `$('td > a[href*="vtick=XXXXXX"]').parent().removeAttr('onclick')` might be closer.

Comment: @minitech awesome! that was what it needed, a two step pass `$('td > a[href*="vtick=XXXXXX"]').parent().removeAttr('onclick');
$('td > a[href*="vtick=XXXXXX"]').attr("href","#");` Does the trick. Thanks! Add it as answer and i'll accept

Comment: You don't need two steps: `$('td > a[href*="vtick=XXXXXX"]').attr("href","#").parent().removeAttr('onclick')`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, i didn't think you could chain modifiers together that way. But then again i'm not fully versed in all things Jquery.

Comment: Any jQuery method that doesn't return some other value returns the collection it was called on, so you can chain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:contains` searches the text content of an element; CSS selectors provide `*=` (in the typical brackets) to match anywhere in an attribute value.

```
$('td > a[href*="vtick=XXXXXX"]')
    .attr('href', '#')
    .parent()
    .removeAttr('onclick');
```